# how to give the access rights to files to upload them on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, visual-studio, web-services

I have uploaded my project on server. Now when i am trying to upload any file from my project to the server , it gives an error that " you do not have access to the path..."  . Where path is server's web hosting directory path.

How can i solve this error.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of IIS is this?  What identity is your the worker process's application pool running under? You may need to grant write permission to ASPNet, NetworkService, or the identity that your web application/web service is running as

Comment: @Tung, Rohan have obviously some problems even understanding the difference between "a log" and "to log in", so I'm afraid he won't answer these questions...

Comment: Thank. @Tung for guideing me. i have solved my problem by setting access rights in my hosing control panel. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the control panel your hosting provider gave you the access to. If you go through the settings, I bet you'll find that setting easily.

Comment: thanks for reply. I am hosting my project on godaddy. And i am also getting hosing directory path but i dont get how to give rights to that directory?

Comment: @Rohan did you manage to log into your control panel successfully?

Comment: @Roha, I didn't say anything about a log, I'm talking about LOGGING IN to your control panel. You put your credentials in the form and get access to the settings of your web hosting. If you can't figure it still out, refer to the e-mail your provider surely sent you when you registered there. It should contain basic information on how to upload your website, what are your credentials to control panel, its address etc.

Comment: thanks for guideing me. i have solved my problem by setting access rights in hosting control panel. : )

Answer (score 0):

On the server, right click on the folder=> properties=>security tab.

Select which user to access the folder and give modify or full permission. Get more help from your administrator.